# how to get tag value from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="block4[messageType = '103']">
        <xsl:value-of select="block4/tag[name = '32A']/value"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="block4[messageType = '102']">
        <xsl:value-of select="block4/tag[name = '32B']/value"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

xml looks like

```
<block2>
    <tag>
        <name>32A</name>
        <value>051028EUR6104,42</value>
    </tag>
</block2>
```

for me value was getting but in tht value i need upto first six characters

so that output looks like **051028**

Comment: actually i need only first six char in that particular value

Comment: Are you really asking for XPath [`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(block4/tag[name = '32A']/value, 1, 6)" />
```